# Python script to texture paint across active viewport

Tags: python, texture-painting

Can't wrap my head around the python API docs for texture painting, I've got the brush and UV mapping setup, just need to automate the brush painting across the active viewport, it doesn't need to be precise at all. Any code snippet would be of huge help.

For example, this is a crudely applied texture painting that I've done manually. 
[image: Example]

I want to be able to automate the process, all I really need is for the brush stroke to go through everything in the active viewport. I can automate the switch between front,left,right and back ortho views to cover the whole face.

If that isn't possible, alternatively I could split the head into different vertex groups and just apply the paint per vertex group.

Comment: Please add more detail and a reference image showing what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Added more detail.

Comment: How do you handle the boundaries where the image textures don't match when automating the projection? Texture baking isn't a better method here? How are you preparing the source images - are they each loaded with separate UV maps?

Comment: Each source image is for a separate UV map, yes. The source image lightning is somewhat normalized to avoid very obvious seams between the different source images. I'm going to be switching the source images while using the same UV map and model and then saving the resulting "base" texture. That's why I need to automate it this way.